# How do I get the tabulate() function in R to include the value of zero? Are there other options?

Tags: r, matrix

I have a test data set called "predicted" that results after taking 100 bootstrap samples from a random normal distribution. Predicted is filled with integer data (from 0 to 20).

When I use the following function:

```
predicted_output <- as.matrix(tabulate(predicted, 
    nbins = max(0, predicted, na.rm = FALSE)))
```

I observe that all counts associated with [0,] are excluded from the resulting matrix (as per the description in the tabulate data, which notes that NAs are (silently) ignored). How do I (or can I) augment tabulate to provide a matrix which, in my case, has 21 rows, and includes the counts for the NULL values?

Comment: If you can show us (mock) data and the desired result, I'm sure we can cut it and slice it for you.

Comment: Why not use `table`?  `tabulate` is a low-level function that is not convenient to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A easy workaround is to change `NA` values to `max(predicted)+1`. And you can get the counts of `0` as well by doing `tabulate(predicted+1)`:

```
x <- c(1,1,0,0,0,2,3,7,10,NA,5,2,NA,10)
x[is.na(x)] <- max(x, na.rm=T) + 1
tabulate(x+1)

# [1] 3 2 2 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 2 2
```

**Note that** the count for **0's and NA's** are also **included** above. The first value = 3 is the number of 0's and the last is the count of NA's.

you can check this with:

```
x <- c(1,1,0,0,0,2,3,7,10,NA,5,2,NA,10)
table(x, exclude=NULL)

# x
#    0    1    2    3    5    7   10 <NA> 
#    3    2    2    1    1    1    2    2
```

Comment: Thanks for the initial help. Imagine that predicted includes these values: 19 19 15 19 17 17 19 19 20 19 17 19 20 19 20 20 20 0 13 15 17 18 16 20 19 19 3 6 0 4 8. When I just use tabulate(predicted) the 0 terms are not included (only values from 1 to 20 are included). I need the zero's because on some models the data is heavily skewed toward the lower margin.

Comment: I just did the following: a <- c(19,19,15,19,17,17,19,19,20,19,17,19,20,19,20,20,20,0,13,15,17,18,16,20,19,19,3,6,0,4 and generated the following after using tabulate(a) ... [1]  0  0  1  1  0  1  0  1  0  0  0  0  1  0  2  1  4  1 10 6 ... the zero value doesn't appear to be counted

Comment: Thanks. Let me review and attempt to implement your solution.

Comment: That works well! Thanks. I need to understand better what the +1 is doing specifically when it is inside the tabulate(predicted+1) function. Can I use that I wonder to also count negative values?

Comment: Thanks very much. Very well explained. Thanks again!